# Multiplying doubles, none of which are equal to zero gives me zero

Tags: c++, for-loop, logic

[The Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L22Bl.png)

[The Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GOs0.png)

The problem is in the calcdrag function, where in the for loop the equation for drag yields zero despite the fact none of the variables in the equation are zero.

Comment: Post the code & output, not links to them.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Links to code and output are not recommended as they constutute poor formatting and is much harder to reproduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're dividing 2 integers here: `double D = (1 / 2)...` and that gives you zero.

Try `double D = (1.0 / 2)...`

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. I was stuck on that way longer than I should have been.